# What was the quantified brain volume of Albert Einstein?

Tags: neuroscience, neuroanatomy

I have read articles stating that Albert Einstein had an average brain volume but couldn't find a specific measurement. I'm curious because the articles are all so ambiguous. He could have been on the upper or lower side of average.

Comment: You may want to check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein's_brain)'s references (the page itself doesn't seem to have your answer).

Comment: @NickStauner Right. I looked through the references and couldn't find anything. I also searched google with no success.

Comment: as a bit of light relief you may find something of relevance in Michael Paterniti's "Driving Mr Albert" http://www.amazon.com/Driving-Mr-Albert-America-Einsteins/dp/038533303X

Answer (score 4):

I was interested in the same question a while ago. Unfortunately, Witelson et al (1999) reported here (http://penthai.sc.mahidol.ac.th/html/articles/newsletter/paper3.pdf) that  volume measurements haven't been taken at the time. Weight data is available, but weight and volume aren't correlated perfectly.

Witelson, S. F., Kigar, D. L., & Harvey, T. (1999). The exceptional brain of Albert Einstein. The Lancet, 353(9170), 2149-2153.